# Laravel:: MAMP is not letting me to access localhost folders when virtualhost enabled

Tags: php, apache, laravel, mamp

So I am working on Laravel APP. As per Laravel direction I added a virtualhost `mysite.dev`. On enabling virtual host by commenting out the line:

`Include /Applications/MAMP/conf/apache/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf`

So if I access a URI like `http://localhost/folder` it shows:

```
NotFoundHttpException in RouteCollection.php line 161:
```

Why is it considering every folder a `Laravel app`?

**etc/hosts**

```
127.0.0.1       localhost
127.0.0.1       app1.dev
127.0.0.1       app2.dev
```

**extra/vhostfile**

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@dummy-host2.example.com
    DocumentRoot "/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/xx/xx/sourcecode/app2/public/"
    ServerName app2.dev
    ServerAlias app2.dev
    #ErrorLog "logs/dummy-host2.example.com-error_log"
    #CustomLog "logs/dummy-host2.example.com-access_log" common
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Well, we may be good, but we are not _that_ good that we can somehow magically guess your configuration and setup. You will have to tell us. Keep in mind that we cannot look over your shoulder...

Comment: @arkascha hahaa pardon..adding

Comment: @arkascha Question updated.

Comment: Well, most likely `localhost` is resolved as the default host in your http server. Since you have only one virtual server defined that one will be used. I assume the setup in that hosts document root is such that the `laravel` routing mechanisms apply.

Comment: @arkascha something to do with htaccess?

Comment: What should have something to do with some `.htaccess` style file? The host stuff or the laravel behavior? The first obviously not, the second probably is the internal logic of laravel. If that is implemented in a primitive manner using such file or if it replies on things like the index document setting in apache is something I cannot say. But I don't think that is relevant for your question. You asked by a request to `http://localhost/folder` results in a laravel error. Which I explained above, or at least suggested a scenario that might be the reason.